# Putty pscp Illegal file descriptor format error

Tags: checkpoint

i am trying to backup my checkpoint using putty pscp with the cmd:

`pscp -r admin@<ip address>:/var/log/CPbackup/backups/R77/<file_name.tgz> D:\test_location_on_windows`

I get the error:

`Protocol error: Illegal file descriptor format`

I tried looking around google for this, really couldn't find much.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: This question is off topic here. I suggest you ask this on [su].

Comment: @TeunVink alright, asking at superuser. Thanks.